# neo4j how to use count(distinct()) over the nodes of path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I search the longest path of my graph and I want to count the number of distinct nodes of this longest path.

I want to use `count(distinct())`

I tried two queries.

First is

```
match p=(primero)-[:ResponseTo*]-(segundo)
with max(length(p)) as lengthPath
match p1=(primero)-[:ResponseTo*]-(segundo)
where length(p1) = lengthPath
return nodes(p1)
```

The query result is a graph with the path nodes.

But if I tried the query

```
match p=(primero)-[:ResponseTo*]-(segundo)
with max(length(p)) as lengthPath
match p1=(primero)-[:ResponseTo*]-(segundo)
where length(p1) = lengthPath
return count(distinct(primero))
```

The result is

```
count(distinct(primero))
2
```

How can I use `count(distinct())` over the node primero.

Node Primero has a field called id.

Answer (score 2):

You should bind at least one of those nodes, add a direction and also consider a path-limit otherwise this is an extremely expensive query.

```
match p=(primero)-[:ResponseTo*..30]-(segundo)
with p order by length(p) desc limit 1
unwind nodes(p) as n
return distinct n;
```